# JPA Update with Join

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have what I hope is a simple JPA question.  Say I have the following class structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foo_table")
class Foo{
    @Id @Column(name="ID")
    String id;
...
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID")
    Bar bar;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="bar_table")
class Bar{
    @Id @Column(name="ID")
    String id;
    @Column(name="COL3")
    String col3;
}
```

Scenario: Say I want to update which "Bar" a "Foo" record is associated with.

Here's the query I'm using so far:

```
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
int rowsUpdated = em.createQuery("UPDATE Foo f SET bar = :bar " +
                  "WHERE f.id = :fooId").
                  setParameter("fooId", fooId).
                  setParameter("bar", newBar).
                  executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

Question: Is it possible to do in JPA update which only updates only foo_table, but not bar_table.  The DBAs don't want to give me update privileges for bar_table, but it seems that JPA wants to do a "deep" update and updates both foo_table and bar_table.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't remember wrong, `@ManyToOne`'s default behaviour is to cascade the persist down to the referenced object. In your case, this means that `Bar` will be updated too. You can control this with the folloing annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={})
@JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID")
Bar bar;
```

This will mean that persisting the `Foo` object won't affect the `Bar` object.

Comment: I don't have cascadeType.NONE.. here are my options: ALL, DETACH, MERGE, PERSIST, REFRESH, REMOVE

Comment: My bad... Could you try `cascade={}`? I might be mixing things up here, but I have a feeling I have had a similar problem...

Comment: I'll give that a try.  There's also the "updatable" attribute on @JoinColumn annotation.  I'm trying setting that to false.

Comment: @rtcarlson It looks like your solution should work. Could you please let me know if mine works too? Otherwise I'll probably have to remove this answer. :)

Comment: Seems both solutions work.. I'll give you the checkmark though and post mine as an alternate.  Someone could certainly give feedback to whether one is "more correct" that the other.  thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, thanks. I think there is another "cascade" annotation where you can specify `NONE`. Meybe it's hibernate specific, can't remember right now.

Answer (score 3):

This solution also works:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID", updatable=false)
Bar bar;
```